# How do I reset message.content in discord.js?

Tags: discord.js

Basically, what I'm trying to do is detect if a message is being sent, reset the content of that message and await a new reply and then check the content of that message for something in specific. The code looks something like this:

```
if (message.author.id === "318414570161045505") {
    message.channel.send(`${message.author}` + " silence");
    if (message.content.toUpperCase().includes("no")) {
      console.log(message.content)
    }
  }
```

I hope I made myself clear on my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`message.channel.awaitmessages`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages)

```js
if (message.author.id === "318414570161045505") {
    message.channel.send(`${message.author}` + " silence");
    if (message.content.toUpperCase().includes("no")) {
        message.delete()
        const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id && m.content === '??????'
        message.channel
            .awaitMessages(filter, {
                max: 1,
                time: 60000,
                errors: ['time'],
            })
            .then(collected => {
             let messageCollected = collected.first()
            })
            .catch(collected => {
            }
}
    });
```